# BuildContext when using GetX

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I try refactor my flutter app and start using GetX library.
I using library "flutter_form_builder", and some methods here need BuildContext argument. For example:

```dart
String? Function(T?) FormBuilderValidators.equal<T>(
  BuildContext context,
  Object value, {
  String? errorText,
})
```

I try add as argument Get.context, but Get.context type is `BuildContext?` not `BuildContext`
Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: If you are sure that `Get.context` won't be null, then you could add an exclamation mark to tell Flutter that you're sure it won't be null at runtime. `Get.context!`

Comment: Thanks, it's nice Idea, so now I have two ways:
`Get.context!` or `Get.context as BuildContext`
What is better?

Comment: The exclamation mark is used to explicitly tell the null-safety checks that you know for sure the value will not be null at runtime. If you do not know that for sure, then you probably should not go that route because the whole point is to prevent runtime exceptions which you would be circumventing.

Comment: I strongly recommend you avoid using Get.context because it is against flutter BuildContext concept. Try to pass context through your methods wherever  you need.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Get.context` which comes from the `Getx` package when you need it outside your UI, and mark it with `!` so it will be a `BuildContext` type:

```
Get.context // this is BuildContext?
Get.context! // this is BuildContext
```

you can also cast it directly like this:

```
Get.context as BuildContext // this is BuildContext
```

Note: using `Get.context` requires that you need to change `MaterialApp` with `GetMaterialApp` so it will never be null, otherwise it will throws a `null` error